# How to view images/photo stored as a blob in mysql using node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js

I have saved images as blobs directly to a mysql database with other data column fields. Using Node.js, I can view all the data using  an ajax request, however I am not able to view the images as value.Image.
('')

They all appear to be broken. Even though I am using base64 encode.

```
              //(1)getting all data from database in the backend]

              app.get("/alldata", (req, res) => {
          db.query("SELECT * FROM stores", (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (!err) res.send(rows);
        else console.log(err);
         });
            });
```

```
           //(1) - Datalist
           $(document).ready(() => {

           $('#allData').click(() => {
            if ($('#stores').is(':empty')) {
            console.log('It is empty, data can load');
           $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:5000/alldata',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: (data) => {

          $.each(data, function (key, value) {

          //PRINTING TO SCREEN IMAGE AND RECORD DATA                          

          station_data += '<div class="store">' + '<img 
          src="data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,'+ 
          base64.encode(value.Image) +'" width="70" height="70">' + 
         '<li>ID: ' + value.ID + '</li>' +
            '<li>Station: ' + value.Station + '</li>' +
            '<li>Address: ' + value.Address + '</li>' +
            '<li>Sales: ' + value['Monthly C-Store Sales'] + '</li>' +
            '<li>Operator: ' + value.Operator + '</li>' +
            '<li>Top SKU: ' + value['Top SKU'] + '</li>' + '</ul>' +
            '<div class="store-action">' +
            '<input type="hidden" value=\'' + JSON.stringify(value) + 
            '\'>' +
            '<a class="edit" href="http://localhost:5000/edit/' + value.ID 
            + '">Edit</a>' + '  |  ' +
            '<a class="delete" 
            href="http://localhost:5000/stationNames/number/' + value.ID + 
            '" id="del">Delete</a>' +
            '</div>';
        });

           $('#stores').append(station_data);

        }
       });

     } else {
    //console.log('It is not empty, data should not load');
    $('#stores').toggle();
  };
});
```

});